# magento 2 clear white page install

Tags: php, macos, magento, mamp-pro

That's is my first time to trying install Magento 2.

As server i'm using MAMP pro with Apache + php + Nginx + MySql

I'm downloading a `.zip` file and take this to htdocs. Then i'm creating a DataBase in phpMyAdmin like ``` Mage``2.2.6 ```

Then i'm going to `http://127.0.0.1:8888/Mage2.2.6/setup/` and what i see? Yeah - this is a clear white page with-out errors. What is that? Who can answer - because it's really my first time experience with Magento. Why i can't install this?

Mistake :

What i see in php_error.log:

```
    [24-Oct-2018 13:43:49 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Magento\Framework\Exception\FileSystemException: The file "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Mage2.2.6/var/.regenerate" cannot be deleted Warning!unlink(/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Mage2.2.6/var/.regenerate): Permission denied in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Mage2.2.6/vendor/magento/framework/Filesystem/Driver/File.php:382
Stack trace:
#0 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Mage2.2.6/vendor/magento/framework/Filesystem/Directory/Write.php(172): Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Driver\File->deleteFile('/Applications/M...')
#1 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Mage2.2.6/vendor/magento/framework/Code/GeneratedFiles.php(99): Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Directory\Write->delete('/var/.regenerat...')
#2 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Mage2.2.6/vendor/magento/framework/App/ObjectManagerFactory.php(110): Magento\Framework\Code\GeneratedFiles->cleanGeneratedFiles()
#3 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Mage2.2.6/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(209): Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManagerFactory->create(Array)
#4 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Mage2.2.6/v in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Mage2.2.6/vendor/magento/framework/Filesystem/Driver/File.php on line 382
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1475297/phps-white-screen-of-death

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a file permission problem.

Does the web server application have permission to delete files in the /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Mage2.2.6/var/ directory?

Comment: how i can fix this?

Comment: It really depends on how your server is configured, but the key thing is that the webserver application (Apache in your case) is able to have write access to the website files. You may need to read up on linux file permissions, but be careful as setting permissions incorrectly can cause security issues. If this is going to be used in production I would suggest it is setup by someone who understands file permissions.